# Overload Operator for Type Define in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, hex

I have

```
typedef std::string OrderID;
```

I would like to overload the operator ++ for this. The value of OrderID starts out at 1 and is just incremented using hex every time. Possible values are...

001

002

...

00A

00B

...

00F

010

...

1) Can you overload operators for specific type defines, so that std::string++ is not overloaded?

2) Can you increment like above (using Hex)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define

```
OrderID& operator++(OrderID& x)
{
     //...
}
```

it will apply to `std::string` as well.

<del>You should use **composition** instead.</del>

You should use a free function that does that, not necessarily on your defined type. It could also manipulate a string, and that's fine.

```
void incrementString(OrderID& x)
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot make a separate overload. `OrderID` is exactly the same as `std::string` in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the real solution is to define a new type that composes of `std::string` and/or other types, and which then only exposes *what's relevant for the interface of an Order-Id-class*.

E.g., do you really think that exposing a method `OrderId::find_last_not_of(...)` to all users of `OrderId` is a good idea?

Better compose with it, and make it typesafe:

```
class OrderId {
public:
    ...
    foo frob () const { 
        ... rawData_ ...
    }

    OrderId& operator++();    // prefix
    OrderId  operator++(int); // postfix

private:
    std::string rawId_;
};
```

and follow YAGNI for the interface. Keeping interfaces small is the number one secret to reusable, maintainable and robust code that doesn't couple to much with client code.

And also: Only overload operators if it makes sense, your clients should immediately be able to explain what incrementing an order-id means. E.g., it makes sense to increment integers, it makes sense to increment statistical counters, but it wouldn't make sense to increment cars. So, go the way of least suprise, and re-think whether  `operator++` makes sense at all, or if you should use a named function instead, e.g.:

```
OrderId successor (OrderId oid) {...}
OrderId predecessor (OrderId oid) {...}
```